# pairwise_cor() in R: p value?

Tags: r, text, pairwise

I am using R to perform pairwise correlations between keywords from journal articles. However, my question is whether pairwise_cor() provides p values or not? If not, could you tell me whether I have other ways to get p values in the pairwise comparison? Here is my code. Thank you very much.

`SE <- read.csv("/Users/apple/Desktop/SE_Test.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

And here is a screenshot of my data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16IkXnFAzLDxdkBFJTOIg9M7aZF4oDLxx/view?usp=sharing

```
SE_keyword <- tibble(id = SE$ID, keyword = str_to_lower(SE$DE)) %>% unnest(keyword)
SE_keyword %>% group_by(keyword) %>% count(sort = TRUE)

keyword_cors <- SE_keyword %>% 
  group_by(keyword) %>%
  filter(n() >= 3) %>%
  pairwise_cor(keyword, id, sort = TRUE, upper = FALSE)

keyword_cors
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)
library(widyr)
library(broom)
library(Hmisc)
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: survival
#> Loading required package: Formula
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Hmisc'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     src, summarize
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     format.pval, units

gapminder %>%
  pairwise_cor(country, year, lifeExp)
#> # A tibble: 20,022 × 3
#>    item1      item2       correlation
#>    <fct>      <fct>             <dbl>
#>  1 Albania    Afghanistan       0.966
#>  2 Algeria    Afghanistan       0.987
#>  3 Angola     Afghanistan       0.986
#>  4 Argentina  Afghanistan       0.971
#>  5 Australia  Afghanistan       0.939
#>  6 Austria    Afghanistan       0.956
#>  7 Bahrain    Afghanistan       0.996
#>  8 Bangladesh Afghanistan       0.947
#>  9 Belgium    Afghanistan       0.963
#> 10 Benin      Afghanistan       0.997
#> # … with 20,012 more rows

gapminder %>%
  select(country, year, lifeExp) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = country, values_from = lifeExp) %>%
  column_to_rownames("year") %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  rcorr() %>%
  tidy()
#> # A tibble: 10,011 × 5
#>    column1   column2     estimate     n  p.value
#>    <chr>     <chr>          <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
#>  1 Albania   Afghanistan    0.966    12 3.53e- 7
#>  2 Algeria   Afghanistan    0.987    12 3.06e- 9
#>  3 Algeria   Albania        0.953    12 1.62e- 6
#>  4 Angola    Afghanistan    0.986    12 4.88e- 9
#>  5 Angola    Albania        0.976    12 5.95e- 8
#>  6 Angola    Algeria        0.952    12 1.82e- 6
#>  7 Argentina Afghanistan    0.971    12 1.67e- 7
#>  8 Argentina Albania        0.949    12 2.54e- 6
#>  9 Argentina Algeria        0.991    12 4.67e-10
#> 10 Argentina Angola         0.936    12 7.39e- 6
#> # … with 10,001 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Sorry that I did not state my data clearly. Because the keywords are extracted from each journal article, there is no "value". You can refer to the screenshot here (ID: article ID; DE: keyword): https://drive.google.com/file/d/16IkXnFAzLDxdkBFJTOIg9M7aZF4oDLxx/view?usp=sharing

Could you tell me how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Your question was about having p values for pairwise correlations. This is why I proposed a way to get them. Once you know how to call `pairwise_cor`, you can just replace the column names in my answer. A screenshot is not an appropriate way to share data, because nobody can load them into their R session.

Comment: I see. I succeed. Thank you for the sharing.